# Inserting BLOB not working in PHP MySQL (Image field is empty in database)

Tags: php, mysql

I am required to save images as a BLOB in a mysql database. My table consists of an ID, name varchar(255), and BLOB. I am well aware that this is bad practice, but this is what's required of me.

I want to insert a image into a database:
here's my php code in a file called functions.php:

```
function addImage($name, $photoURL) {
    global $conn; // Access the global database connection

    // Sanitize user input to prevent SQL injection
    $name = $conn->real_escape_string($name);

    // Read the image data from the URL
    $imageData = file_get_contents($photoURL);
    $imageData = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $imageData);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (name, image) VALUES (?, ?)";

    // Create a prepared statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    // Bind parameters
    $stmt->bind_param("sb", $name, $imageData);
    ?> 
    <script>
        console.log(<?php echo $imageData?>);
    </script>

    <?php
    // Execute the prepared statement
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        // If the insertion was successful, return true
        return true;
    } else {
        // If there was an error, return false
        return false;
    }
}
```

I made sure $photoURL is correct because I console logged it and it turned out correct in terms of position, its a string which stores the position of the image.SO basically want I want to do is get the link of the image, then insert that image into the database as a BLOB.

My problem is that im assuming $imageData is empty or an error is occurring as according to phpmyadmin, the image column is empty for all entered data.

Heres my add.php code too just in case you wanna see it:

```
<?php
require('config.php');
require('functions.php');
// Initialize variables for form fields
$name = $image = '';
$error = '';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Handle the form submission to add a new artist
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $filename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $tempname = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    $folder = "./image/" . $filename;
    // Move the uploaded file to the destination folder
    move_uploaded_file($tempname, $folder);

    if (addImage($name, $folder)) {
        // Return a JSON response indicating success
        echo json_encode(["status" => "success"]);
        exit();
    } else {
        // Return a JSON response indicating an error
        echo json_encode(["status" => "error"]);
        exit();
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Add</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <main>
        <h2>Add Image</h2>
        <form method="POST" id="add-image-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="genre">Image File</label>
                <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit">Add Image</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php if (!empty($error)) { ?>
            <div class="error">
                <?php echo $error; ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <button id="home-button">Home</button>
    </main>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script> <!-- Include main.js -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When using placeholder values, as you should, **do not** escape manually. This mangles the inserted data, and *badly*.

Comment: PSA: It's often better to use an object-store, like Amazon S3 or equivalent, to store large binary assets, then keep a  reference to that in your database. Filling up your database with large binary assets can complicate backups, massively increase restore times, and perform very poorly in terms of serving performance compared to an object-store system which specializes in such things exclusively.

Comment: I don't know where you got this code from, but it's a mess. Why do you jump from `$conn->real_escape_string()` in one line to `mysqli_real_escape_string()` in another? Why are you using global variables? And you should not be outputting `<script>` elements from the middle of your PHP code, although I hope it was just for debugging.

Comment: Why are you saving the file to disk _and_ to the database? This seems a bit redundant.

Comment: `im assuming`...why not debug it and find out? Then you don't have to guess. We can't tell you for definite if either of those things is happening. Enable PHP error logging, and enable mysqli error reporting. Add some logging or echoing to test the variable values at different stages. That way you'll have a much better idea of what's happening (or isn't happening).